# Proving $e^{\binom{n}{2}}>n!$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $$e^{\binom{n}{2}}>n!$$

$n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$

Sorry, couldn't attempt it.

Comment: It will have to be $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is that the same as $\mathbb{N}$? I changed it :)

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is an irritating thing, because consensus isn't complete about whether $0\in\mathbb N$. I believe most assume $0\in\mathbb N$, so you want $\mathbb Z_+$.

Comment: Ok, fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I wasn't sure if people use $\mathbb{Z}^+$ or $\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hint: Use $\binom{n}{2} = 0+1+2+\cdots+(n-1)$.

Comment: Does that mean $0+1+2+\cdots+(n+1)>ln(n!)$ Where do I do from there?

Comment: Second hint: $e^{0+1+2\dots +(n-1)}= e^0e^1e^2\dots e^{n-1}$. Or just try induction on $n$.

Comment: Am I allowed to assume that $e^n>n+1,n \in \mathbb{N}$? Otherwise, how can I prove it?

Comment: Can you prove $e^n>1+n$, perhaps? (It's only true for $n>0$. $n=1$ gives equality.) How do you define $e^n$?

Comment: $e^{n}=\frac{n^{1}}{1!}+\frac{n^{2}}{2!}+\frac{n^{3}}{3!}+\cdots$ so the inequality must be true, right?

Comment: @user2357 You are missing a term. Is $e^0=0$?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, it should be $e^n=1+n+\cdots$ so it is bigger then the other side since we are adding something positive to $1+n$. Thank you a lot for the assistance. I really need to learn to prove things properly :(

Answer (score 2):

I quite like Thomas Andrews' approach. Alternatively you can estimate
$$
\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k <\int_1^{n+1}\ln x\,dx.
$$
And calculating that integral gives you a good enough upper bound on the r.h.s. Admittedly this needs more machinery, but it also gives a better approximation to $n!$.